# android component enabled boolean

Tags: android

Android components like Activity have a boolean that can be set in AndroidManifest.xml, called enabled. The documentation says that it decides whether or not the system can instantiate that component. I want to ask what is benefit to a developer by setting this flag to false ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9284868/1668144) it can be modified via PackageManager at Runtime.

In my opinion it can be useful for free/paid app development, it is a way to easily keep project branches as similar as possible. Also if it is possible to modify this value at runtime it can be an easy way to implement a "Post-purchase" access to premium version of the application.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. The only thing I can think of is that the Activity is not "complete" yet or deprecated. You can still call methods within the Activity you just can't launch it.